# Is there any justification for the claim that blood travels 12,000 miles per day?

Tags: blood-circulation

An oft-quoted "fact" on the internet<sup>**1**,**2**,**3**</sup> (and at least once in print<sup>**4**</sup>) is the claim:

> Your body has about 5.6 liters (6 quarts) of blood. This 5.6 liters of blood circulates through the body three times every minute. **In one day, the blood travels a total of 19,000 km (12,000 miles)**—that's four times the distance across the US from coast to coast.
>
> <sub>Source: https://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/heart/heartfacts.html</sub>

None of the instances I've found provide any justification for the 12,000 miles figure; nor do they cite any authoritative source.

Although the 12,000 miles figure occurs often, it is fairly obvious that most (if not all) instances are copied from one of the other instances. Sometimes word-for-word, sometimes paraphrased; sometimes with a mention of the other instance, more often with no mention of the source. It is therefore quite possible that someone "*plucked a number out of the air*" and the meme-dispersal properties of the internet have done the rest.

In trying to justify this claim (see *Background* and *Further Research* below), it becomes clear that an awful lot depends on what precisely is meant by "*the blood*" and – to a lesser extent – what is meant by "*the distance traveled*". Some *plausible* definitions could put this figure at anywhere from around 70-90 miles up to around 90 million miles (and, *in extremis*, even a couple of thousand *trillion* miles!). *It is entirely possible that there is no **meaningful** answer to the question of how far blood travels in a day*.

### Question(s)

- Is there any extant, authoritative (*ideally* peer-reviewed) source for the 12,000 miles claim (i.e. that might have been the original source for the above "fact")?
- If the 12,000 miles *has* simply been plucked from the air, is there any extant, authoritative source for a different figure?
- If there is *no* extant authoritative source for any such figure, can someone provide a justifiable and evidence-backed answer to the question "*How far does blood travel in a day*"? (But see note below.)

**Please note**: I am slightly hesitant at including the third option above, and may remove it if felt appropriate. I recognize that the underlying question is likely ambiguous, and that any attempt at an answer might well be "*opinion based*" (as it will probably need to interpret exactly what is meant by "*the blood*" and "*the distance traveled*"). At the risk of being over-demanding, any attempt at answering under this option *must* include fact-backed justification for any such interpretation(s) and *ideally* would justify why such interpretation(s) are the only valid ones. I an ***not***
looking for speculation along the lines of "*If we define "the blood" **this way** and follow **these calculations**, we end up with **this figure**.*".

---

### Background

In the pub a while back, someone had the book [1,342 QI Facts To Leave You Flabbergasted](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/0571332463/)<sup>**4**</sup>. This was opened at random to the "fact" that in one day, "*blood travels 12,000 miles*". I don't have the book in front of me to give its exact wording, but the accompanying [Source Finder website](https://qi.com/1342/index.php)<sup>**5**</sup> points to the PBS quote at the top of this question.

Our first thought was "*that's Quite Interesting*" (which, after all, is the point of the show/book). Our second thought was "*that sounds very high*"... if "the blood" travels 12,000 miles in a day, it travels 500 miles in an hour, and clearly (at least at a simplistic level), blood isn't coursing through our body at 500 mph!

Some further pondering, and a little web-searching on mobiles didn't clarify things: our conclusion  was (as noted above), that too much hinged on what exactly is meant by "*the blood*" and how you measure "*the distance traveled*". Some clearly wrong interpretations:

- We found a figure of 3-4 mph for the average speed of blood-flow<sup>**6**</sup> . Treating "the blood" as a homogeneous fluid, this would give a "total distance traveled" of between 72 and 96 miles over a 24-hour period.
- Clearly 12,000 miles isn't the distance traveled by an individual blood cell, as that would necessitate it traveling at the aforementioned 500 mph.
- It's clearly not based on the *total* distance traveled by *all* blood cells. An adult male has around 25 **trillion** (25,000,000,000,000) red blood cells (RBCs)<sup>**7**</sup>.  If each is traveling on average at 3-4 mph, the total distance for all cells would be roughly 2,000 trillion miles in a day (or about 350 light-years – a little more than the distance to [Canopus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canopus), the second brightest star in the sky). Conversely, if the total distance was 12,000 miles, each RBC would travel less than a thousandth of a millimetre (about the wavelength of red light).

We did have some thoughts about trying to account for the multiple paths that "the blood" flows through. In an extremely simplified example, suppose blood from the heart split into two parallel paths, each of which went around the body before merging just before re-entering the heart. It *could* be argued that "the total distance" was **2** x 4 mph x 24 hours, since "the blood" was going down two channels. However, it could also be argued that what is going down each channel is not "the blood" but "half the blood".

Things get more complicated when more realistic topologies are considered: if the blood flows through a common vessel (e.g. the aorta) before splitting, *if* you count each path separately (as above), should the shared path count double or only once? You *probably* want something in between based on the relative lengths of the single path and the multiple paths.

My view is that while this *might* be a way of deriving a plausible figure, it is not without problems. One is practical: you'd need to map the entire circulatory system in order to correctly assign weights to each branch and arrive at an overall multiplier. Another is numerical: as we scale up to the full system, there is a danger the multiplier grows too quickly (remember: 80% of the system is formed from capillaries, and the smallest of these are no wider than a blood cell... there will be *a lot* of paths). Finally, what's being measured feels increasingly arbitrary: the contribution from the aorta is from all the blood at once; but from the capillaries it is almost cell-by-cell.

Between the two extremes above – 70-90 miles when treating blood "as a whole", and 2 thousand trillion by counting each cell – you could probably arrive at almost *any* number for the total distance traveled. Our problem was that we could not think of a natural way of "dividing the blood" and counting "the distance" that would arrive at 12,000 miles. Further research would be required...

---

### Further Research

Over the next couple of days, I did some dedicated web-trawling... with little success.

The 12,000 miles kept cropping up, but with no justification as to where the number came from, and no references to an authoritative source. I also collected the following, potentially relevant "facts" about the heart and circulatory systems (generally, where it matters, for an adult male):

- Blood travels an *average* of 3-4 mph<sup>**6**</sup>. Faster in the aorta; slower in the capillaries (where cells need to pass in single-file, and sometimes have to "push" their way through). Another source<sup>**10**</sup> gives a slightly wider range (2.2 to 4.5 mph).
- The total length of all arteries, capillaries and veins is about 60,000 miles<sup>**8**,**3**,**9**</sup> (with capillaries making up about 80% of this total).
- There is about 5.6 litres (6 quarts) of blood in the body<sup>**1**,**6**,**9**</sup>.
- Blood takes about 20 seconds to circulate throughout the entire vascular system<sup>**1**,**9**</sup>.

The only *discussion* I could find on the subject was a Reddit thread<sup>**11**</sup>, which starts:

> Does human blood really travel 12,000 miles every day?
>
> Someone posted that on Facebook and I thought it was total bullshit. So I Googled it and it seems it's not bullshit? I guess my real question then would be: isn't there something more to this? That's 500 miles per hour. I can't understand how that wouldn't rip your body apart.

which neatly mirrors our experience: lots of pages quoting 12,000 miles, no references, and a feeling that 500 mph is clearly wrong. There follows some loose speculation, including that the total distance traveled by *all* blood cells is clearly massively too high; as is a figure of about 90 million miles calculated by multiplying the number of times the blood circulates in a day (1,440) by the total length of the circulatory system (60,000 miles). To me, the most pertinent comment is the closing one from user [rm999](https://www.reddit.com/user/rm999/):

> I searched online, there's nothing reputable backing this. The figures I see are closer to <1 mph, which would be on the order of ~20 miles a day.

although rm999's figure for the overall speed is less than the most common figures I saw (although <sup>**3**</sup> quotes this speed for the aorta).

---

### References

<sup>**1**</sup> [Amazing Heart Facts](https://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/heart/heartfacts.html) on the *Nova* section of the PBS website.

<sup>**2**</sup> [The Journey of Blood (PDF)](https://www.heart.org/idc/groups/heart-public/@wcm/@fc/documents/downloadable/ucm_454347.pdf). Lesson plan on the American Heart Association website.

<sup>**3**</sup> [Slideshow on "Circulation"](https://slideplayer.com/slide/6366571/) on slideplayer.com by Dwain Gibbs.

<sup>**4**</sup> [1,342 QI Facts To Leave You Flabbergasted](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/0571332463/): a spin-off book from the British TV comedy panel game-show "*QI*" (for "*Quite Interesting*") – see [entry on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QI). Despite being primarily an entertainment show, it has a [pretty good reputation for research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QI#Research), although it does sometimes [make mistakes and issue corrections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QI#Mistakes_and_corrections). I *suspect* the book is less thoroughly researched than items appearing on the TV show.

<sup>**5**</sup> The book lists its sources on https://qi.com/1342/index.php (this can be seen using the *Look Inside!* feature on the Amazon page above, under "*Read This First*"). The "12,000" miles fact is the second entry on page 186, leading to the aforementioned http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/heart/heartfacts.html.

<sup>**6**</sup> [Our Bodies' Velocities, By the Numbers](http://discovermagazine.com/2014/julyaug/18-body-of-work) on the *Discover* magazine website. Note, though, that after giving the 3-4 mph figure, it goes on to say "*But this blood speed is just an average. It starts out by rushing through the aorta at an impressive 15 inches a second, then slows to different rates in various parts of the body.*" I suspect the "inches" is a mistake: 15 inches/second equates to less than 1 mph; whereas 15 **feet**/second equates to about 10 mph, which fits better.

<sup>**7**</sup> [How many blood cells are in the human body?](https://www.healthline.com/health/number-of-cells-in-body#blood-cells) from the article "*How Many Cells Are in the Human Body?*" on the Healthline.com website.

<sup>**8**</sup> [11 Surprising Facts About the Circulatory System](https://www.livescience.com/39925-circulatory-system-facts-surprising.html) on the Live Science website.

<sup>**9**</sup> [Heart Facts](https://health.clevelandclinic.org/heart-facts/) on the Health Essentials website of the Cleveland Clinic. The "*20 seconds to circulate*" fact was originally taken from *Amazing Heart Facts* on the Arkansas Heart Hospital website, but that link (https://www.arheart.com/heart-health/amazing-heart-facts/) is no longer valid.

<sup>**10**</sup> [What is the speed of blood circulation in human body?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-speed-of-blood-circulation-in-human-body) on Quora.

<sup>**11**</sup> [Does human blood really travel 12,000 miles every day?](https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/427tlz/does_human_blood_really_travel_12000_miles_every/) on Reddit.

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. You are to be commended on the thoroughness of your investigation. This sort of question is not the sort of thing that concerns the majority of professional scientists — I personally term it "freak show science" or "Guinness Book of Nonsense" — but there may be someone here interested enough to check your figures. They seem plausible enough to me.

Comment: This might be more on-topic at skeptics.SE ? You're asking to confirm a published statement/claim, that happens to be about biology.

Answer (score 8):

**A single erythrocite** travelling from the heart via the aorta, a certain artery, capillary and vein back to the heart would make about 1 meter in average, I guess.

If the [blood volume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_volume) of an adult is ~5 liters and if the [cardiac output](http://ccnmtl.columbia.edu/projects/heart/circ2.html) is ~5 liters per minute, then **"all the blood"** travels 1 meter in a minute, which is 60 meters per hour or **1,440 meters (~0.9 miles) per day.**

This seems to roughly agree with:

> Average peak and mean blood velocities were 66 and 11 cm/sec in the
>   ascending aorta, 57 and 10 cm/sec in the pulmonary artery, 28 and 12
>   cm/sec in the superior vena cava, and 26 and 13 cm/sec in the inferior
>   vena cava. *([The blood velocity...(Circulation)](https://ahajournals.org/doi/abs/10.1161/01.cir.40.5.603))*

So, if you say that the average blood velocity in big vessels is 12 cm/sec or 432 m/hour and consider that the velocity in smaller vessels is much lower, then it is possible that the average blood velocity in all the vessels could be ~60 m/hour, as I estimated.

> But if you took all the blood vessels out of an average child and laid
>   them out in one line, the line would stretch over 60,000 miles. An
>   adult’s would be closer to 100,000 miles long. *([The Franklin Institute](https://www.fi.edu/heart/blood-vessels))*

You can then say that **"all separate blood streams"** (5 liters in summary) going through all the vessels would make 100,000 miles in a minute or 144,000,000 miles in a day. But not "all the blood" travels all that distance in a day.

I'm not sure how they came to 12,000 miles per day, but this just shows how different the things can look from different perspectives.

EDIT: I just noticed that my "calculation" 144,000,000 miles is 12,000 miles squared.

Comment: Just guessing, but I would suppose that someone saw the figure 1200 m(eters) per day, read it as 1200 m(iles) per day, sayd "Oh, wow!", posted about it somewhere, and the post repeatedly got copied without fact-checking.

Comment: @jamesqf, such things can happen...Anyway, blood travelling 12,000 or no matter how many miles or meters per day is not really an useful information. I answered just to show how the confusion can develop.

Comment: The radius of Earth is ~25,000 miles, so using the center of the earth as a reference frame someone at a moderate latitude would see their blood (and the rest of them) travel about 12,000 miles in a day. I think the 1200 meter explanation is a likely explanation, but overall I think the point that this answer makes (i.e., it totally depends on how you define the trivia) is important, and is consistent with David's point that this sort of estimation isn't really relevant to a biologist.

Comment: @BryanKrause, you probably meant circumference...and the blood would then travel 25,000 miles a day...?

Comment: @Jan Er, yes of course circumference. Only at the equator would it be 25000, somewhere in the mid latitudes it would be 12000.

Comment: @Bryan Krause: But you're still neglecting the motion of the Earth as it revolves around the Sun (about 67,000 mph/107,000 km/h), the Sun moving around the galactic core, our galaxy's motion WRT the local group...

Comment: @Jan: The speed of blood flow would be useful information when designing things like stents & replacement heart valves.  E.g. if blood actually did travel 12,000 miles per day, that would be 500 mph, which would cause some serious turbulence, among other problems.

Comment: @jamesqf, knowing the speed is useful, of course - and the actual speeds are not calculated but measured. They are all those miles that I don't find useful.

Comment: @jamesqf I know, that's why I referred to the center of the earth as a reference frame (I got that detail right even if I misspoke about the radius/circumference ;) ) And yes, knowing the speed of blood flow itself is useful, but the way you'd figure that out is by measuring the speed of blood flow in a vessel of interest. You don't much care about it's velocity elsewhere, and it would likely mislead you if you calculated an average velocity given the differences between capillaries, veins, and arteries.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to come up with an explanation with approximate values. It looks like 12,000 miles is actually milliliter-miles per day. The way to think about is to consider a drop of blood that is part of a heart pump (1 ML) doing roundtrip though the body (say a string of 3.33 meters). There are 56 drops of blood in a heartbeat. If you are to keep 56 strings end to end then the cumulative distance travelled by 56 drops of blood is 3.33*56=186.48 meters. Then if we multiply this distance by number of heart beats per day then we get the 12000 miles number.

- 56 : milliliters - amount of blood per pump
- 72 : pumps per minute
- 56*72 = 4,032  : milliliters per minute
- 4032*60 = 241,920  : milliliters per hour
- 241920*24 = 5,806,080  : milliliters per day
- 1.67 : meters - height of average adult
- 1.67*2 = 3.33 : meters - roundtrip travelled by blood
- 5806080*3.33 = 19,353,600 : milliliter-meters per day
- 19353600/1000 = 19,353 : milliliter-kilometers per day
- 19353/1.61 = 12,021 : milliliter-miles per day
- Note: I am not the person who came up with 12,000 miles per day claim. Since there is no citable source for the claim, I am only trying to come up with a possible explanation for the circulated number.

References:

1. The web pages below claim that blood travels approximately 12,000 miles per day.
   https://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/heart/heartfacts.html
   https://www.heart.org/idc/groups/heart-public/@wcm/@fc/documents/downloadable/ucm_454347.pdf
2. The web page below says heart rate range is 60 to 100 beats per minute. I chose 72 which is within the range.
   https://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/fitness/expert-answers/heart-rate/faq-20057979
3. The web page below says amount of blood per pump is 55-80 milliliters. I chose 56 which is within the range.
   https://www.smm.org/heart/lessons/lesson2.htm
4. The web page below talked about human height. I chose 167 which is within the range.
   https://ourworldindata.org/human-height

Comment: I'd understand if it got a quarter of the way there with every pump, but that's not what your calculation shows. Do you have a ref. to show that your assumption is correct? I.e. that a particular set of blood goes out the heart, and back again in one beat-cycle?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

As blood flows at a rate of 3 to 4 mph or 4.8 to 6.4 kph call it 5kph in 24hours it will have travelled some  120km or 12,000 metres please note METRES not miles.
Too many people misread or misquote things without checking and some actually get printed in quiz books.

Comment: Thanks for this, although that should be "_120km or 120,000 metres_", shouldn't it? However, someone confusing meters and miles _and_ slipping a power of 10 seems a very plausible explanation for where the "12,000 miles" came from (I only ever worked things out in miles, so never spotted the similarity of the "simple" distance in metres).